# Hook on compiler / Hook on the output of a method (C# - c++)

Tags: c#, c++, compiler-construction, hook, compare

Well to start ill tell u what i have to do.

I have to make a program so students can upload some C++ code from an exercise. And this uploaded code needs to get compared with the "best code" from that exercise. And from those comparisation the server gives back some feedback if the student uploaded good or bad code. 
EG: the Exercise is to make an arraylist from 1 to 10 and so the student can upload his code. The server then compares it with some other code and gives feedback.

This is easyer said then done, because it can't be just a file comparer because of the different variables a user can code. Thats why i was tinking of using external compilers to get some output and compare this output with the output of the "best code". Or more detailed to get a hook within the compiler so i can check every method and every variable.

Or any other idea how i can check this or compare?
Or is there already a program that exist?

Very thanks,
Michael

Comment: Have fun. You propably don't realize *how incredibly right* you are saying that this is "easier said than done". Anyway, have a look at Clang - a C/C++/ObjC compiler explicitly designed to be hackable and reusable as libraries in other projects.

Comment: You must also take into account the BigO notation!

Comment: How simple are the exercises?  If it's any more than a line or two, simply comparing it to a nominally best example won't be useful.  Try to automate that and lots of students WILL show up and overflow office hours showing good solutions that were listed as bad.  Stick to it and the professor WILL get a deservedly bad rep among the students, and nowadays those bad reps are often published for all to see.

Answer (score 0):

There are systems that assess the output of the whole program (like [ejudge](http://www.ejudge.ru/download/?locale_id=2), it is used as a contest system), and, in my opinion, it's easier to use them, because specifying conditions on the program code is itself not a trivial task (if your students are writing non-trivial programs).
You can use formal specification languages like ACSL to set input and output conditions and prove that the program works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more practical to evaluate the code by testing the behaviour against some automated tests, like a boundary test suite (or even a mutant test if you want things to get exciting), and then to look for odd implementations or interesting architectures look at  code metrics like number of functions, lines of code, compile size, etc. .

This approach would be a lot more scalable, and there is a lot of free tools, especially for c++ and java that would be easy to set up an automated test system.

Comparing code to determine correctness is not necessarily a correct approach, depending on how it is done, and would be very difficult to scale up.